# Password with word and 4 generated characters

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've the following script and I want to generate a password with the pattern `TEMPPW` + 3 numbers and 1 special character. What do I have to change in this script?

```
#
# Description: Wlacza konta, resetuje hasla i ustawia zmiane hasla przy pierwszym logowaniu.
#
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web 
# Pobiera liste kont z pliku UserList.txt
# Jeden user na wiersz, bo sie wysypie. 
$users = Get-Content -Path 'G:\Shares\xx xxx\ResetPassword\UserList.txt'
#
ForEach ($user in $users) 
{
$unsecuredpwd = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10, 3)
# Szyfruje haslo, a potem podstawia je w miejsce zmiennej unsecurepwd.
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $unsecuredpwd -Force
# Ustawia haslo dla konta.
Get-ADUser $user | Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $password -Reset
# Wymusza zmiane hasla przy logowaniu.
Get-ADUser $user | Set-AdUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
# Wlacza konto.
Enable-ADAccount -Identity $user
Write-Host “uzytkownik: $user”
Write-Host “haslo: $unsecuredpwd”
Write-Host “ `r`n`r`n”
}
Read-Host -Prompt "Nacisnij enter, zeby wyjsc"
```

Answer (score 2):

Generating a random 3 digit number is fairly easy, use `Get-Random` with the `-Minimum` and `-Maximum` parameters:

```
# Maximum is exclusive, largest potential output is 999 
$RandomNumber = Get-Random -Minimum 100 -Maximum 1000
```

Generating a random "special character" is easy as well, we can grab one of the symbols from the ASCII range between 33 and 47 (`! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . /`):

```
$RandomSpecialChar = [char](33..47 |Get-random)
```

So to generate the whole password, we can use the string format operator (`-f`) and do:

```
$unsecuredpwd = "TEMPPW{0}{1}" -f (Get-Random -Minimum 100 -Maximum 1000),[char](33..47 |Get-random)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since Martin doesn't want to answer, I'll do it ;)
you would want to do something like this:

```
$a = 'TEMPW'
$a += -join ((48..57) | get-random -count 3 | % {[char]$_})
$a += -join ((58..64) | get-random | % {[char]$_})
```